# CSS: Is it possible to set a CSS property to a portion of an HTML Attribute?

Tags: css

Let's say I have a attribute like this: `test="key1-Value1 key2-Value2"`. I know there's the `attr()` function for getting attribute values, but what if I wanted just `Value2` in the attribute? If I could, I'd use regex like this: find `key-2(.+)$`, and replace with `$1`. Do you have any ideas how I could accomplish this, if possible?

**Edit:** I want to be able to have an attribute like specified above and be able to write properties like for example, `color: Value2`, with `Value2` extracted from the attribute.

I want to have a bunch of different elements with varying attributes, and not have to hardcode all the rules for them. Ideally I could do this with just CSS since I'm writing a theme for an Electron App where I can't (without going well out of my way) write custom JS for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want this…

```
/* <a> elements whose class attribute contains the word "logo" */
a[class~="logo"] {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

So…

```
[test~="key2-Value2"]
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Thanks, though I realized I should've clarified. I want you to look at my edit.

Comment: Ah ok. I see. Basically no. Even attr() is only supported for content and not color as you’re wanting (it’s there but experimental and that’s just for the whole attribute value anyway, nothing like you’re wanting with a regex). Does it have to be CSS? JavaScript could do this easily.

Comment: I could write JS if I really wanted to. The app is called Obsidian, which has a JS API for plugins, but I don't have the time to learn JS and the whole API do so, and it would be a lot of work. If I ever did, then I'd ask a question about doing so if I couldn't figure it out even with googling.

Comment: It’s a line or two of JS. If you ask a separate question I’ll happily answer. If you wanted to upvote and accept this answer it would be appreciated. I can write up my previous comment to the answer if that helps. Edit: no doubt I’m understating the difficulty of implementing it with JS but the basic process is simple enough.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking you could write JS that like works in a browser, but it would be more work to make it work with the Obsidian API. Do what you want, I am happy you're willing to help though.

Comment: Yes exactly, that’s what I was hinting at and agreeing with you about in the edit. I or others could give you some simple JS to do what you need but then some work would be necessary to integrate that with the system you’re working with. I do think it’s easier than you imagine though. Probably you’d just need a question or two on the implementation side and you’re done. Or there may be good examples in the docs for the system and unlikely you’d need to understand the whole thing.

Comment: But the thing is idk if it could be easily implemented with the Obsidian API. Why don't you take a look at it and see if that's the case or not? https://marcus.se.net/obsidian-plugin-docs/